# How do I make a EditableText or TextField in flutter multiline and wrapping?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want a way to make a TextField or EditableText's text wrap onto another line. 
And how to make them multiline.

I don't know if it matters, but the  EditableText sits inside a ListTile > Card > Container.

This is my code:

```
return ListTile(
  title: Card(
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: EditableText(
        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        controller: _textEditingController,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 18.0,
        ),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        cursorColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

It doesn't work please help. I have searched everywhere now!

I'm running flutter version: 0.4.4 and dart version: 2.0.0-dev.54.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the property `maxLines` to either null (for infinite growth) or a fixed number.

By default `maxLines` is equal to 1.

Comment: Aah null, of course! Thank you. I tried setting it to 100 earlier but that just caused overflow errors. Anyway thanks!